# Array of Structures in C with MPI

Tags: c, struct, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

I am having a relatively a problem,I have defined struct and I want the array of structure  has this information (processor name and the computation time for the processor) this is part of my code :

```
struct stru
{
   double  arr_time[50];
   char pname[50];   
};
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

struct stru all_info[50];

   MPI_Status status;
   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&process_id);
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&num_of_processes);

    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
    int name_len;
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name, &name_len);
if (process_id == 0)
{  //do somthing
}
if (process_id > 0)
{  
    double start = MPI_Wtime();
    for (k=0; k<array_size; k++)
      for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
      {
          c[i][k]=0.0;                     
          for (j=0; j<array_size; j++)
           c[i][k] = c[i][k] + a[i][j] * b[j][k];
      }      
      end_time = MPI_Wtime() - start;  
        all_info[i].arr_time[i] = end_time;
      for (int i=1 ;i <= numworkers ;i++)
            strcpy( all_info[i].pname, processor_name);

         printf(" time  = %f  for processor %s 
         \n",all_info[i].arr_time, all_info[i].pname);

}


      MPI_Gather( &end_time, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, &all_info[i].arr_time, 1, 
       MPI_DOUBLE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

if (process_id == 0){

      for(i = 1; i <= numworkers; i++ )
      {
         printf("  time   %f  for processor %s 
         \n",all_info[i].arr_time , all_info[i].pname);
 }     }
```

I have no result if I print it in  if `(process_id == 0)` !!! 
the out put is

```
 time   0.000000  for processor  
 time   0.000000  for processor  
 time   0.000000  for processor
```

and just the time printed if I printting in `if (process_id > 0)`

In fact I don't know how can I use Structure with `MPI` can anyone give me advice how can I generate array of structure that has processor name and his time? 
Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: Please indent & format your code properly, it's hard to read now.

Comment: this is part of my code I'm just asking how can I putting (end_time and processor_name ) in array of structure ?

Comment: It's a matter of being nice and formatting code well prevents mistakes.

Comment: Meanwhile, please make the effort to post a correctly indented code that compiles.

Comment: @Gilles Gouaillardet , all the idea I want the array of structure must has the name and time for each processor that work in parallel (each processor has time and name)

Comment: are you using several usernames on SO ?
anyway, the latest edit of your code does not make any sense at all.
if your question is "how to gather a `C` structure that contains an array of `char` and a `double` ?", then write a (correctly indented) [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and let's resume from that. if you are not even willing to indent your code properly, then you should consider paying someone to do your homework, and SO is not the right place for that.

Comment: pardon , what do you mean "are you using several usernames on SO " ??!! I'm just have a problem in using struct with mpi !!

Comment: that sounds like a yes to me https://stackoverflow.com/users/9035138/dania

Comment: No account for me other than this, thanks !

Answer (score 3):

At this line:

```
processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
```

you start using the array variable `processor_name` without defining it anywhere.

You're missing something like `all_info[i].` in front of it. Like you have a bit lower:

```
all_info[i].processor_name;
```

Then, for storing a string your `processor_name` needs memory. A single `char` is just one byte (i.e. one letter). So let's assume these names are **never** longer than 255, you'd get:

```
struct stru
{
   double end_time;
   char   processor_name[256];   
};
```

There are so many basic things wrong in your code and your questions seem to indicate that you lack basic understanding of C programming. Therefore my advice would be to take more time studying this language.

Comment: I defined it in structure, but I don't know if this true or no ?

Comment: I do your update  and this error I have ( error: ‘processor_name’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
 )

Comment: I update my code and I got rid of the mistake , but I have no result when printing the result ... thank you and Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: for this hint  "char   processor_name[256]; "  plus one

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs here because you have not defined any type `processor name`.
If I understand what you're trying to correctly, it seems like you were trying to access the attribute of the structures. For doing that, you might need to use the `.` operator. For that you might need to define an array

```
struct stru all_info[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];
```

instead of

```
struct stru all_info[50];
```

Comment: in this case I reache just for the processor name ?? is that correct ??

Comment: I want all info array must contain the processor name and the time that I compute

Comment: I update my code and I got rid of the mistake , but I have no result when printing the result .